# How to get colored output from bash script?

Tags: bash

When I execute `grep` from within gnome-terminal, I get colored output - easily noticeable match, line-numbers (-n) with different colors etc

But when I execute exactly same `grep` command through bash script I get plane output, without coloring

Is there a way I can get colored output by using bash script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the `--color` option works for me out when I run grep inside of shell scripts.

Here is an example of what you want.

```
grep -n --color=auto "PATTERN" FILE
```

Comment: Indeed thanks. I browsed grep man page but `--color[=WHEN], --colour[=WHEN]` confused me, although it's explained fine

Answer (score 3):

Here's a small script that helps you to grap how tput works with bash

```
#!/bin/bash
#@auth kesavan.muthuvel
#@desc - bash with colors :)

B=`tput bold`           #BOLD
D=`tput dim`            #DIM
U=`tput sgr 0 1`        #UNDERLINE
U2=`tput smul`          #UNDERLINE2
NOU=`tput rmul`         #NO UNDERLINE
H=`tput smso`           #HIGHLIGHT
X=`tput sgr0`           #RESET
C='tput setaf '         #COLOR


for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ; do
        c=`$C$i` && echo $c${B}I${U}always$NOU $D love \
           ${U2}colors$NOU \& $c${H}GNU/Linux$X
done;
```

This will print the following output with formats like **BOLD** ,UNDERLINE , Highlighting and colors.

[image: BASH Script prints with Text formating and COLORS]

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to add these alias to your `~/.bashrc`?

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
```

Comment: Yes, those lines are present, but output is unfortunately same (w/o coloring) when grep is run from bash script.

Comment: Shell aliases only have an effect on interactive shell sessions by default. You either need to 1) add the `--color` option to the `grep` command explicitly (safe) or 2) enable the `expand_aliases` shell option and `source ~/.bashrc` (prone to issues because of possible other aliases). You can refine 1) and define a variabl `GREP="grep --color=auto"` and later use `$GREP` instead of `grep` everywhere in your script.