# How do I get a colored bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, colors, bashrc

How can I get the bash to look colored like this?

[image: colored-bash]

Comment: daniel451 how come you have answered for your own question within the same timings.

Comment: @kva Answering your own question at the same time as posting is encouraged across the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/123268/changing-colors-for-user-host-directory-information-in-terminal-command-prompt. It explains how individual parts of the prompt can be coloured differently.

Comment: If you are using Termux then you can Install zshell which will change everything in your terminal, You can read this post fo the installation.https://www.learntermux.tech/2020/02/how-to-install-z-shell-best-theme-for-TERMUX-2020.html

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I came up with this solution:

1. Open `~/.bashrc` in a text editor.
2. Copy this and add it at the end of the `~/.bashrc` file:

   ```
   PS1='\[\033[1;36m\]\u\[\033[1;31m\]@\[\033[1;32m\]\h:\[\033[1;35m\]\w\[\033[1;31m\]\$\[\033[0m\] '
   ```
3. Ssave the file and source `~/.bashrc`:

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```

For a full list of available colors and further options, look up these links:

- [wiki.ubuntuusers](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Bash/Prompt)
- [bash-color-chart](http://abload.de/img/bash-color-chartmxjbp.png)

Comment: You might want to check out liquid prompt. It is a really info packed little prompt. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fnojhan%2Fliquidprompt&ei=RsMAVPnkMYqvggTB8YGgBw&usg=AFQjCNGlCF548NeQ_BIYiUM7pP3mZrA9Rw&sig2=Djd80l6I7dmwTgXOy-8d6A&bvm=bv.74115972,d.eXY

Comment: https://translate.google.se/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.ubuntuusers.de%2FBash%2FPrompt

Comment: Perfect color choice!

Comment: An online GUI, [Easy Bash PS1 Generator](http://ezprompt.net/)

Comment: +1 for the link to the color chart :)

Comment: Okay, this is really sexy. Handy to color code every server differently, for more stonks.

Answer (score 189):

Open `~/.bashrc` in text editor and uncomment line:

`#force_color_prompt=yes`

to be:

`force_color_prompt=yes`

save then execute `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Doesn't exactly answer the question, but I like this result better (less distracting).

Comment: I think it does answer. why not ?

Comment: Here is what mine looks like after your method:

![2016-10-25 16:12:15.png](https://s19.postimg.org/ehb0gg7tf/2016_10_25_16_12_15.png)

Not exactly as in the question.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn force_color only enabled colors, you can always manage how coloring will look like with PS1 variable see my example in one of my scripts https://github.com/to-kra/dotfiles/blob/master/scripts/gitAwarePromptInstall.sh which also enabling git status... you can have your own PS1 exported in user profile, and make fancy colors and format you like. thx

Comment: Is `force_color_prompt=yes` the intended way of enabling colors? To me forcing sounds like a workaround.

Comment: @Jaakko I posted this long time ago, and its quickest way on debian/ubuntu, and its easiest way. I am now using `export PS1` but its only because I wanted to modify appearance of default settings. If you dont want to spend too much time with `export PS1`, then do as i mentioned. thx

Comment: I don't know how the colors are intended to be enabled. I'm just thinking that if there was some other way than "force" for the used console emulator to tell the .bashrc that it can handle colors. Exporting PS1 also feels a bit cumbersome, I'd be totally fine with default colors.

Comment: i got no idea, i alway used force. in answer bellow, which is marked as GreenTick, there is this PS1 way i mentioned. Dunno how else it can be enabled.

Comment: @Jaakko I like your interrogation. The bashrc file claims the following:

``# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned

# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window

# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt

#force_color_prompt=yes``

What do you think about that ?

Comment: I hope I didn't sound disrespectful with my comments, I'm just trying to understand how it was meant to work. For example, above those lines you mention, there's a different way of enabling colors, `xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;` Which makes me think that the colors could automatically enable if you had correct value in TERM variable.

Comment: This is exactly what I want! It's amazing!

Comment: Great tip! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A version that is a bit more 'general' - should work with a varied environment:
*(depends on terminfo)*

Insert this in your `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
function fgtab {
  echo "tput setf/setb - Foreground/Background table"
  for f in {0..7}; do
    for b in {0..7}; do
      echo -en "$(tput setf $f)$(tput setb $b) $f/$b "
    done
    echo -e "$(tput sgr 0)"
  done
}

# The prompt in a somewhat Terminal -type independent manner:
cname="$(tput setf 3)"
csgn="$(tput setf 4)"
chost="$(tput setf 2)"
cw="$(tput setf 6)"
crst="$(tput sgr 0)"
PS1="\[${cname}\]\u\[${csgn}\]@\[${chost}\]\h:\[${cw}\]\w\[${csgn}\]\$\[${crst}\] "
```

Then execute `source ~/.bashrc`.

After that, `fgtab` will display a color table with numbers. Those numbers are for `tput setf n` and `tput setb n` where 'n' is the number, 'f' stands for 'foreground' and 'b' stands for 'background' color.

`tput sgr 0` will reset foreground and background colors to default.

And as you can see, changing the colors used for the prompt becomes really easy (just edit the same number in `$HOME/.bashrc` as you wish).

Add an `$(tput setb n)` in `$cname` if you wish to have ALL of the prompt with background n.

Comment: more: http://askubuntu.com/a/396555/289138

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/ more of the direct number crunching.

Comment: `man 5 terminfo` shows what `tput` can be used with, it is a bit technical though so "take heed" - but a bit of *guessing and testing* may actually let you get it working.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having trouble making "force-color-prompt" to work in Ubuntu 20 using Kitty/Putty.

But notice the following code in the default Ubuntu 20 .bashrc file:
case "$TERM" in
xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

So in Kitty, go to

1. Connection
2. Data

Then change "Terminal-type string" from "xterm" to "xterm-color" and viola!

Answer (score 0):

If you install the minimal Ubuntu you don't get the default .bashrc that has the values for colors and some other stuff. This is the default .bashrc you can use.

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```