# Colors in terminator

Tags: terminator

I'm using terminator with Xubuntu 16.04. Unfortunately the terminal text does not highlight anything, when I used terminator on Linux Mint the `username@computer:` was highlighted in different colors and weight. Now its all plain text.

Answer (score 10):

This question has already been answered here [How to get a colored bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517677/how-to-get-a-colored-bash)

This has nothing to do with terminator

the easy way to have your colour "back" your shell is to uncomment one line in your `.bashrc`

Open`~/.bashrc` in text editor and uncomment line:

```
\#force_color_prompt=yes
```

to be:

```
force_color_prompt=yes
```

save then execute source`~/.bashrc`

hope this help