# Ubuntu 17.10 .bashrc at start up

Tags: 17.10, gnome-terminal, bashrc

The terminal on my Ubuntu 17.10 didn't have any text colors, So I found a solution and got it fixed in **.bashrc**, so now my terminal have text colors. But the problem is every time I open a new tab in terminal, i need to run this command `source ~/.bashrc` to get the colors working. Is there a way that I can avoid running this command all the time?

Comment: @NerdOfCode answer solved my issue. I wonder why people suggested useing .bashrc in this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/517677/how-to-get-a-colored-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1

If this is a problem all users are facing in your system... Perhaps consider adding it to `/etc/profile` as this runs each time a user is logged in???

#### Method 2

If you do not want to use that method you can simply add something like `source ~/.bashrc` to the bottom of the `/etc/profile` for it to automatically do this...

But anyways... Either method should fix your problem...

Comment: I used Method 2, work like a charm.

Comment: @Zhenyu Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use .`bashrc`, use .`profile` instead. .`bashrc` is not guaranteed to run on interactive shell.