# Lost terminal color hi light, getting only one color

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, colors

I installed ubuntu 18.04 and put arc ambiance as theme. After doing this (or, maybe something more that I not remember) my terminal has only text color(my user name, @, text, things in ls, etc). How can I get back the color hi-light?

I searched on google, but I found no solution. There is a way to reinstall the terminal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but I just figured out a solution to this! The reason for this is that your home directory doesn't contain a specific file to allow these kinds of color operations within Terminal.

**To fix this:** ***(Make sure all terminal windows are closed before proceeding)***

Open Nautilus/File Manager and turn on the 'Show Hidden Files' option. From there, check to see if you have a `.bashrc` file in your Home directory.

If you do, delete it as there's a fresh, unconfigured back-up copy we'll add back into there later.

If you don't, no problem! To get a new, fresh copy of this file, navigate to `/etc/skel/.bashrc`. Copy this file and paste it in your Home directory.

From there, open a new Terminal window, you should be all set as all other color options are visible (bold, cursor, highlight). You can now change and modify the color within the Preferences within Terminal. You can also [manually change](https://askubuntu.com/a/517678/998511) the colors by editing the `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Insted of closing all terminal windows you can do these operations in one of them and after that you can run `source .bashrc`. This command will reload your bash configurations from the new `~/.bashrc` file