# Laptop screen shows colors tending to gray

Tags: screen, colors

I have a Dell Precision 6600, under 16.04LTS.
Sometimes I find that colors turn in general to somewhat gray (as it is now, and I cannot get out of this).
Then, for some unknown reason, the screen comes back to normal.

Checking pure white (FFFFFF) for instance shows as gray, in any application.
I tried answers here:

[How do I adjust the screen contrast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91195/how-do-i-adjust-the-screen-contrast)

[Script to display all terminal colors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27314/script-to-display-all-terminal-colors)

**What can I do to solve this?**
A reboot (or even a logout) possibly solves this, but I mean to identify the cause and solve it without logging out.

Answer (score 0):

I had several windows from screenshots open.
Each of them lightly shifted colors towards gray, with the result being a noticeable change.
Closing each one of them gradually removed that tendency, finally leading to a "healthy" image.