# Display Git branch in brackets inside Ubuntu terminal using custom .profile script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, git, .profile

I have this custom `.profile` script:

```sh
PS1='\[\033]0;WSL2 Bash\W\007\]' # set window title
PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[36m\]'       # change to green
PS1="$PS1"'bash@bexgboost '         # user@host<space>
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[31m\]'       # change to brownish yellow
PS1="$PS1"'\W'                 # current working directory
if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
then
    GIT_EXEC_PATH="$(git --exec-path 2>/dev/null)"
    COMPLETION_PATH="${GIT_EXEC_PATH%/libexec/git-core}"
    COMPLETION_PATH="${COMPLETION_PATH%/lib/git-core}"
    COMPLETION_PATH="$COMPLETION_PATH/share/git/completion"
    if test -f "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
    then
        . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-completion.bash"
        . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
        PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[35m\]'  # change color to cyan
        PS1="$PS1"'`__git_ps1`'   # bash function
    fi
fi

PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[0m\]'        # change color
PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
PS1="$PS1"'$ '                 # prompt: always $
```

Currently, it looks like this when I launch the terminal:

[image]

The script was supposed to show the branch name like this:

[image]

> Ignore the mismatch in dir names.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is at line 18:

```bash
PS1="$PS1"'`__git_ps1`'   # bash function
```

Here you are using command substitution (old style by backticks) where you calling the function `__git_ps1` and it should be replaced by its output, but I can't see the definition of the function in your example code. So I think you can add the following function definition somewhere before that line:

```
__git_ps1() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
```

Then save and source the profile file - `. .profile`, and it should work.

---

In addition, here is a working example, where the default `~/.bashrc` file (I prefer to edit this file instead of `.profile` in this case) of Ubuntu Server 22.04 is changed to be achieved almost the same as your desired look. Note here I'm using the new syntax of command substitution `$()`. And the function `parse_git_branch()` is defined before its calling.

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    #PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]' # green
    #PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;33m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]' # yellow
    #PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;34m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]' # blue
     PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;35m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]' # purple
    #PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]' # red

     PS1="${PS1}\[\033[01;33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[0m\]\n" # HERE WE CALL THE FUNCTION THAT PARSE THE BRANCH
     PS1="${PS1}\$ "
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

Only the relevant lines of `.bashrc` are shown. For the default state find the statement `if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ];` (around line 70) in your `.bashrc`.

Here is how it looks in practice:

[image]

- Note I'm using GNOME terminal within Kali Linux to connect to Ubuntu Server and this is the reason why the colors are slightly different from these that will be produced by the same code on Ubuntu.

References:

- Ask Ubuntu: [Script to display all terminal colors](https://askubuntu.com/q/27314/566421)
- Coderwall: [Add git branch name to bash prompt](https://coderwall.com/p/fasnya/add-git-branch-name-to-bash-prompt)

Comment: I fıgured ıt out earlıer from another thread, but thank you anyways! Thıs seems to work.

Comment: Thank you for the bashrc part of the answer
Just understood a little more about the scripting part